# What is rgb in RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt( byte[] rgb, bool fOAEP )

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, naming-conventions

What is rgb in `RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt( byte[] rgb, bool fOAEP )`?

I mean, what do r, g and b stand for?

(My knowledge on cryptography is near to nothing.. so please pardon my question if you think the answer is very simple)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx

Comment: @CBroe That link describes what the parameter is for (it's the value to be encrypyted). It does not explain why it is called `rgb` which is what the question author is asking.

Answer (score 5):

`rgb` in [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aHungarian_notation#Origin.2C_Systems_vs._Apps) is "range of bytes".

It's an interesting question, but it doesn't have to do with cryptography, as demonstrated by the fact that both Encrypt and Decrypt take rgb as the parameter for the plaintext and ciphertext, respectively.

I'd also like to point out that the `fOAEP` parameter is not only using [hungarian notation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you shouldn't do in C#, but is using it incorrectly since it is not a flag.